# AWS Lambda Error EADDRINUSE on every invoke

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, aws-lambda

I created a Nodejs AWS Lambda function which is accessed through API Gateway and it worked fine until yesterday. However, without me doing any changes to anything, it does not work anymore.

Whenever I try to invoke the function, it immediately terminates with the Error

```
{
    "errorType": "Error",
    "errorMessage": "listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use 0.0.0.0:3000",
    "code": "EADDRINUSE",
    "errno": -98,
    "syscall": "listen",
    "address": "0.0.0.0",
    "port": 3000,
    "stack": [
        "Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use 0.0.0.0:3000",
        "    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1318:16)",
        "    at listenInCluster (net.js:1366:12)",
        "    at Server.listen (net.js:1452:7)",
        "    at Function.listen (/var/task/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:618:24)",
        "    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/app.js:433:5)",
        "    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1068:30)",
        "    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)",
        "    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:933:32)",
        "    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:14)",
        "    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:19)"
    ]
}
```

My function doesn't even do anything. I tried to remove everything to check if it's human error but the error still occurs. Right now, the only thing that my function does is:

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
AWS.config.update({ region: "eu-central-1" });
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var awsServerlessExpressMiddleware = require("aws-serverless-express/middleware");

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(awsServerlessExpressMiddleware.eventContext());

app.get("/bids/:auctionid", async function (req, res) {
  res.json({ success: "true", url: req.url, body: "call success" });
});
```

The error happens on every lambda call.

Comment: Looks like you are starting a server that is listening on port 3000 which is already taken. Could it be some express.js server?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by switching to port 3001

Comment: This means you had something running already on port 3000 (such as a nodejs server for example).